# Wordpress post time comperation

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time, strtotime

i need to separate posts older than 2017-07-01.

In loop i'm using these two codes for displaying blogposts.

```
$compare_date = strtotime("2017-07-01");
$post_date = get_the_date();
```

and trying to compare them like

```
if( $compare_date >= $post_date ){
    //old
}else{
    //new
}
```

but abviously it didnt work because one of them returns `1498867200`
and other one `1 Haziran 2017`
I also tried putting `strtotime(get_the_date())` but that result is empty.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the post_date in the same format as compare_date

Now compare with dates

```
$compare_date = "2017-07-01";
$post_date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' );
if( $compare_date >= $post_date ){
    //old
}else{
    //new
}
```

Now compare to time

```
$compare_date = strtotime("2017-07-01");
$post_date = strtotime(get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ));
if( $compare_date >= $post_date ){
    //old
}else{
    //new
}
```

Not tested, but workable solution.